# Shield UI Grid Hyperlink on a Column Value

Tags: hyperlink, grid, shieldui

I am trying to use the values in a given column as a hyperlink using Shield UI's Grid.  There doesn't appear to be anything on making a value within a column a hyperlink in the documentation.

Does anyone have an idea how to make a hyperlink within the grid?

example:

File_001  (href="\somefolder\File_001.pdf")

File_002  (href="\somefolder\File_002.pdf")

etc...etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [column format option](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/columns/format) to add custom HTML markup in your cells like this:

```
columns: [                
    { field: "id", width: "70px", title: "ID" },
    { field: "name", title: "Person Name" },
    { field: "company", title: "Company Name" },
    { 
        field: "email", title: "Email Address", width: "270px", 
        format: function(val) { return '<a href="mailto:' + val + '">' + val + '</a>'; }  
    }
]
```